# Displaying most popular posts on my blog - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a simple blog application using Ruby on Rails, both of which I am new to. I am trying to get my most 'voted' posts to display in my /views/posts/index.html.erb view. Here are the basics.

I have created a votes table and successfully allow a user to 'vote' for a post on the /views/posts/show.html.erb page. The VotesController passes the post_id to the Votes table column post_id and returns the vote count for that post via ajax to the same show page.

```
class Vote
  belongs_to :post`
end
```

and

```
class Post
  has_many :votes
end
```

I would like to display in /views/posts/index.html.erb the post title and the amount of times it has been voted for, ordered by posts with the highest vote count.

**EDIT** 
With the code below I have been able to display (in the /views/posts/show.html.erb page) the post_id from the Votes table and vote_count for that post_id. i.e. '55(7)'. Wondering if somehow I can also pass the post_title to the votes table (to column post_title) and then just display that instead of the post_id. Here is the code that is accomplishing that.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

     def index
        @tag_counts = Tag.count(:group => :tag_name, 
           :order => 'count_all DESC', :limit => 20)
        @vote_counts = Vote.count(:group => :post_id, :limit => 5)

        conditions, joins = {}, nil
        unless(params[:tag_name] || "").empty?
          conditions = ["tags.tag_name = ? ", params[:tag_name]]
          joins = :tags
        end
        @posts=Post.all(:joins => joins, :conditions=> conditions, :order => 'created_at DESC').paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
          format.json { render :json => @posts }
          format.atom
        end
      end
```

VotesController

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @vote = @post.votes.create!(params[:vote])

       respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to @post}
       format.js
     end
  end
end
```

/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
Most Liked Posts<hr/>
        <% @vote_counts.each do |post_id, vote_count| %>    
                <div id="tag-wrapper">
                    <%= link_to(post_id, posts_path(:post_id => post_id)) %>
                    (<%=vote_count%>)</div>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Do you realize you're asking almost the same question as in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634981/how-do-a-search-a-table-for-similar-records-and-displaying-count-ruby-on-rails)? The answer is the same -- **Don't** calculate the value at request time, use a counter_cache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the vote_fu plugin for this (use [kandadaboggu-vote_fu](http://rubygems.org/gems/kandadaboggu-vote_fu) version)

```
class User
 acts_as_voter
end
```

Add `vote_total` column(integer) to `posts` table.

```
class Post
 acts_as_voteable :vote_counter => true
end
```

Now you can do the following:

```
user.vote_for(post)       # vote up
user.vote_against(post)   # vote down
post.vote_total           # sum of +ve and -ve votes
post.vote_count           # count of votes
```

If you use the `vote_counter` directive, vote total is maintained in the `posts` table. No extra SQL is needed to calculate `vote_total`.

To sort the posts by vote_total do the following:

```
Posts.all(:order => "vote_total DESC")
```

**Disclosure**

I maintain `kandadaboggu-vote_fu` gem.

**Edit**

To implement this in your current schema, you can do the following:

```
Post.all(:joins => :votes, :select => "posts.*, count(*) as vote_total",
  :group => "votes.post_id", :order => "vote_total DESC", :limit => 10)
```

**Edit 2**

You can use the following code to implement this feature to work with your current logic.
Please note that Rails uses INNER joins, so a post will not be selected if it does not have a vote. You can circumvent this by always voting once when the Post is created.

I have fixed your `paginate` call. Current logic is extremely inefficient. The pagination is applied on the array returned from the DB, so entire result set is loaded before pagination is performed. As rule, treat `paginate` like `all` method with two extra parameter.

Please note that the SQL below will put strain on your system resources. You might have to optimize by storing `vote_total` in the `posts` table.

```
conditions, joins = {}, :votes 

unless(params[:tag_name] || "").empty?
  conditions = ["tags.tag_name = ? ", params[:tag_name]]
  joins = [:tags, :votes]
end
@posts=Post.paginate(
          :select => "posts.*, count(*) as vote_total", 
          :joins => joins, 
          :conditions=> conditions, 
          :group => "votes.post_id", 
          :order => "vote_total DESC",
          :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

**Edit 3**

Logic for voting upon creation of a post.

```
class Vote
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
  after_create :self_vote

  def self_vote
   # I am assuming you have a user_id field in `posts` and `votes` table.
   self.votes.create(:user => self.user)
  end
end
```

Iteration code for posts:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <p><%= link_to(post.title, post_path(post)) %></p>
 <p>
     Created <%=  time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>. 
     Votes <%=  post.vote_total %>
 </p> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think I will give that a shot, but without doing that, couldn't I just pass the post_title to the votes table into a column called post_title and then use @vote_counts = Vote.count(:group => :post_id, :limit => 5) in the controller and replace post_id w/ post_title in the view? Been trying that but can't seem to get it to pass post_id from the votes#index.

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.

Comment: I think "You could use ..." would be more appropriate than "You should use ...". Apart from that, the information provided seems helpful to me. +1

Comment: Updated my answer. Perils of posting without proof reading.. :-)

Comment: @KandadaBoggu I am not sure how to implement your edit given the complexity of the @post method in the PostsController because of the tag functionality. Also, not sure what the view should be. I feel like I have gotten close given the edit above and wondering if it is possible to just tweak that. If not I will restart with your recs.

Comment: Uodated the answer. Take a look.

Comment: Awesome, that seems to work. Is there a way to auto create a vote record for a post upon creation of the new post? Also, what would be the view code for the display of most popular posts in the /posts/views/index.html.erb. This is it man I promise. I feel like I should send you a check.

Comment: Add an `after_create` filter in your Post class(refer to the updated answer). In the view, iterate through the posts array(in @posts) and display them.

Comment: I added the user_id columns and put the updated code in the model. Getting error that says "undefined method `user' for". PostController#create. Assuming I have to add a user method in PostController#create, how would I write that? Also, could you post the code for iterating through the posts array(in @posts). Sorry. I am new.

Comment: You need to add `user` associations to `Vote` and `Post` model. I have updated the code. You should read the Rails bible : Agile Web Development with Rails(http://pragprog.com/titles/rails2/agile-web-development-with-rails). It has answers to most of the questions you have raised here.

Comment: I think I am going to stop down on this thing and do some reading. I can't expect that people will have the time to answer all my questions and really really appreciate your help. I have already learned a lot through this process but don't want to abuse this platform. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you so much for updating that last code block. I was pulling my hair out. If I can just figure out how to reverse the order as it is displaying the least voted for at the top...I am done. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: Ah, doesn't seem to do it. I changed it in the controller for the @posts block and also the @vote_counts block. Am I missing something?

Comment: I meant it for `@posts`. It has to work. For `@vote_counts`, use `:order => 'count_all DESC'`.

Comment: Ok, I see what is happening. There are two :order clauses in @post. The one second from the bottom and the one after the :page clause. The last :order is controlling both the posts that display and also the side bar most liked post section. Seems like it is not allowing for the separating of ordering of those two things.

Comment: Then you need two variables for this. Execute the same statement twice with two different `:order` clause.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean to be honest. Trying like hell.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to show a list of latest posts in the content area and popular posts in the side bar. For latest posts execute the the `all` method with :order => "posts.created_at ASC"(assign the value to @posts). For popular posts execute the  `all` method with :order => "vote_total DESC"(assign the value to @popular_posts)

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the extra clarification. Perfect. Thanks thanks thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use mysql query.Something like following say

```
@posts=Post.find_by_sql("select p.post, count(v.vote) as vote from posts p, votes v where v.post_id=p.id group by p.id order by vote DESC")
```

on rhtml

```
for post in @posts 
  post.post
  post.vote
end
```

Comment: Hard-coding SQL is the worst possible way to accomplish this, when there is a built-in ActiveRecord facility to do it for you.